# How can I get a ridge regression to include the entire dataset?

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression

I'm trying to do a ridge regression on a set of data. My full dataset, voters, has 49978 observations, and my training data had 39983 observations. I built the ridge regression model using the train data and tested it on the test data, and am now trying to apply the model to the entire voters dataset. The issue is that when I run the predictions on the full dataset, it returns only 39983 elements (i.e., only corresponding with the observations in the test dataset.

This is the code to build the ridge regression:

```
set.seed(123)
ridge <- train(
  x, y, data = train.data, method = "glmnet",
  trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 10),
  tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = lambda)
)
# Derive coefficients
coef2 <- coef(ridge$finalModel, ridge$bestTune$lambda)
# Make predictions
newx <- data.matrix(test.data)
predictions2 <- predict(ridge, newx=newx)
```

This is the code I'm using the run the model on the voter dataset:

```
newx <- data.matrix(voters)
fullpredict <- predict(ridge, newx=newx)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! If I'm looking to generate a value based on the prediction for every observation in the dataset, is there any way to do that? (In other words, run the coefficients from the model on everything observation.)

Comment: You should include full code including needed `library` calls and show the evidence that you think supports your clam that the predictions on the "voters" dataset is only from 39983 observations. I'm thinking you would need at a minimum to show `str(newx)` before the final call to predict and `str(fullpredict)`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change `predict(ridge, newx = newx)` to `predict(ridge, newdata = newx)` in both cases.